Problem in adding GIF in React Native App
I'm trying to display a GIF in my React Native App.

I also add animated-gif in android>app>build.gradle.
dependencies {
// The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
// For animated GIF support
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:3.1.3'

if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
    implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
} else {
    implementation jscFlavor
}}

But this only shows as an image, no animation. How to show GIF animation.
